# WebStorm says "no best common type exits among yield expressions" (TypeScript)

Tags: typescript, webstorm

WebStorm says "no best common type exits among yield expressions"

Code example:

```
mo.co(function*(){
yield dao1.findOne...
yield dao2.findOne...

})
```

Other person's WebStorm was OK but my will say that...

WebStorm version: 2017.2.1

one yield is ok!!!

the code compline is ok !!!

unhappy...
unhappy...

[image: pic]

Comment: The first `yield` yields a single `IGmUser`, the second yields apparently an array of `IGmRole`. So there’s not a common type and as such not a common yield type the generator function has.

Comment: @poke thank you very much for your answer.  but is it wrong? i will first  get the gmUser , second i get gmRoles   why it must be the same type?...i don't want to use  (then)  or  (callback).... becasue our company just insist to use two yield!  how i can do  ... i just do not want to see the red underline...  it makes me feeling bad ^^

Comment: and  co(function* () {  
  var a = yield Promise.resolve(1);

  var c = yield fn;

  var e = yield [
    Promise.resolve('a'),
    later('b'),
    fn,
    fn(5)
  ];


});

the code is ok ...but it is js no typescript...

Comment: Your function is yielding *both* types at the same time. That is wrong, yes. Your function should only have one task: Get users, or get roles (but especially not multiple arrays of roles), but mixing both will make it very difficult to consume the function. If you really want to mix types, you will have to explicitly declare the function to return either of those types.

Comment: @poke only return one type(eg:A) .before i return the type(eg:A),I have to query two types (eg:B ,C) so i have to yielding two type(eg:B,C). (A is composed of B and C) two yield in a generation it should be ok...  just my opinion...(thank you very much for your patience)

Comment: If `A` is composed of `B` and `C`, you actually want to return `A`, and you get both `B` and `C` in the function, then you should combine the things in the function and actually return `A` instead of yielding both `B` and `C`. The way you explain it, I don’t believe you actually want to have a generator function.

Comment: @poke http://blog.shiqichan.com/using-es6-generators-in-nodejs/ in the third part of the code     ------- co(function*(){
     var address=[
          '192.168.1.100',
          '192.168.1.101'
     ];
     var p1=yield getMAC(address[0]);
     var p2=yield getMAC(address[1]);

     console.log(address[0]+' ->'+p1);
     console.log(address[1]+' ->'+p2);
     return 'done';
})(function(err,result){
     console.log('err: '+err+', result: '+result);
});

Comment: @poke  ------there is two yield in a function  ,because getMAC() may need cost some time  so  we must use yield.   it is my interpretation. with out yield  our  system may be wait wait wait  for getMAC() ,our system will block...

Comment: That `getMAC` is fine because it returns multiple MAC addresses (the same kind of object). Your function appears to return only one user, and then an array of roles. So only *two* objects and those are always of a different kind. What you should do instead is await both the user and its roles and then combine it into a single type and yield/return only that one. And if you are only retrieving a single user—which your function appears to do because you only pass it a single user id—you should only *return* the user (making your function async and return a promise) instead of yielding.